# How do I merge two dataframes with conflicting values

Tags: r

I'm sorry if this is a duplicate question, but I have looked around at similar problems and haven't been able to find a real solution. Anyway, here goes:

---

I've read a .csv file into a table. There I'm dealing with 3 columns:
"ID"(author's ID), "num_pub"(number of articles published), and "year"(spans from 1930 to 2017).

I would like to get a final table where I would have "num_pub" for each "year", for every "ID". So rows would be "ID"s, columns would be "year"s, and underneath each year there would be the corresponding "num_pub" or 0 value if the author hasn't published anything.

---

I have tried creating two new tables and merging them in a few different ways described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right) but to no avail.

---

So first I read my file into a table:
`tab<-read.table("mytable.csv",sep=",",head=T,colClasses=c("character","numeric","factor"))`

`head(tab,10)
    ID      num_pub    year
1   00002     1        1977
2   00002     2        1978
3   00002     1        1983
4   00002     4        1984
5   00002     3        1990
6   00002     1        1994
7   00002     2        1996
8   00004     3        1957
9   00004     1        1958
10  00004     1        1959`

With that, I was then able to create a table where for each "ID", there was every single "year", and if the author published in that year, the value was 1, otherwise it was 0:
`a<-table(tab[,1], tab[,3])`

Calling `head(a,1)` returns the following table: [pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66T9X.jpg)

---

I would like to know how to achieve the desired result I described above. Namely, having a table where rows would be populated with "ID"s, columns would be populated with "year"s (from 1930 to 2017), and underneath each year, there would be an actual "num_pub" value or a 0 value. The structure of the table would be just like the one shown in the [pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66T9X.jpg)

Thank you for your time and help. I'm very new to R, and kind of stuck in the mud with this.

Edit: the reshape approach as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890584/how-to-reshape-data-from-long-to-wide-format) does not solve my problem. I need zeros in place of "NA"s, and I want my year to start with 1930 instead of the first year that the author has published.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reshape data from long to wide format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890584/how-to-reshape-data-from-long-to-wide-format)

Comment: I tried this approach, but this way I end up with "NA" values instead of zeros. Also, the years with "num_pub" values end up bundled at the beginning, instead of the table starting with year 1930. Thank you all the same though, I didn't know of this approach.

Comment: Simply replace NAs with 0s in a second step: `dat[is.na(dat)] <- 0`. Your second requirement can be solved by building a fake dataset with all author-year combos and then merging onto it. something like `squareData <- expand.grid(authors=authorVec, years=1930:2018)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using `reshape2` & `dcast` one can change to a wide format and then pipe through to replace `NA`s with 0s.

```
library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)

dcast(tab, ID~year, value.var = "num_pub") %>% 
  replace(is.na(.), 0)

     ID 1957 1958 1959 1977 1978 1983 1984 1990 1994 1996
1 00002    0    0    0    1    2    1    4    3    1    2
2 00004    3    1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is precisely the output I was looking for.

Comment: I happen to think this is an excellent answer because the code is essentially self-documenting, but there are some SO purists who might complain that there is insuficient explication.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `complete` to fill in the zeros for non available data, and then `spread` to turn your column of years into multiple columns (both from the `tidyr` package):

```
library(tidyr)

df_complete <-
  complete(df, ID, year, fill = list(num_pub = 0))

spread(df_complete, key = year, value = num_pub)

# A tibble: 2 x 11
  ID    `1957` `1958` `1959` `1977` `1978` `1983` `1984` `1990` `1994` `1996`
  <fct>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 00002      0      0      0      1      2      1      4      3      1      2
2 00004      3      1      1      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
```

#### Data:

```
df <-
  data.frame(ID = c("00002", "00002", "00002", "00002", "00002", "00002", "00002", "00004", "00004", "00004"),
             num_pub = c(1, 2, 1, 4, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1),
             year = c(1977, 1978, 1983, 1984, 1990, 1994, 1996, 1957, 1958, 1959))
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! This was very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

In base R this might be handled with a merge operation followed by some coercion to 0/1 by way of negating `is.na` and using `as.numeric`. (Admittedly the `complete` function appears easier.

```
temp <-  merge(expand.grid(ID=sprintf("%05d", 2:4),year=1930:2018), tab, all=T) 
str(temp)
#--------
'data.frame':   267 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ ID     : Factor w/ 3 levels "00002","00003",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ year   : int  1930 1931 1932 1933 1934 1935 1936 1937 1938 1939 ...
 $ num_pub: num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...

 temp$any_pub <- as.numeric(!is.na(temp$num_pub))

 head(temp)
     ID year num_pub any_pub
1 00002 1930      NA       0
2 00002 1931      NA       0
3 00002 1932      NA       0
4 00002 1933      NA       0
5 00002 1934      NA       0
6 00002 1935      NA       0

tapply(temp$any_pub, temp$ID,sum)
#
00002 00003 00004 
    7     0     3
```

Comment: I did start to try and prepare a solution in base R, but (as you attest), it just isn't that neat.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This was very helpful.